# login.aspx page should redirect to a different page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Forms Authentication and have stored the credentials in the Web.config since there are only two credentials. Currently I have a login page that on authentication would redirect to the default.aspx page or the return url. I want to redirect to a different page i.e. form1.aspx or form2.aspx based upon the credentials.
Currently using

```
if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text))
{
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUser.Text, false);
}
```

Comment: you don't need "Asp.net c#" in the subject line. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
    if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text))
    {
            switch (txtUser.Text)
            {
                    case "alice":
                            Response.Redirect("form1.aspx");
                            break;
                    case "bob":
                            Response.Redirect("form2.aspx");
                            break;
                    default:
                            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUser.Text, false);
                            break;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Response.Redirect.

```
if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text)){
Response.Redirect("URLofPageYouWantToRedirectTo");
}
```